# Adjusting for baseline when time is a covariate, what is the interpretation of $y(t=0)$?

Tags: regression, time-series, baseline

When one aims to estimate the treatment effect over time, it is recommended to include the baseline value as a covariate. Assume continuous outcome $y$, continuous time $t$, categorical treatment $x \in \{0,1\}$. Baseline is defined as the value of the outcome $y$ at $t=0$ and denoted by $y_0$. We fit the regression model:
$$y=\beta_0 + \beta_1 y_0 + \beta_2 x + \beta_3 t + \epsilon,$$
with residual term $\epsilon$. In this model, what is the interpretation of the fitted outcome value at baseline for an individual with baseline score of $0$? The model equation is then:
$$y(t=0,y_0=0) = \beta_0 + \beta_2 x + \epsilon,$$
so the fitted baseline depends on $x$ although the actual baseline value is known to be $0$. What is this model actually modeling?

Comment: First, is your baseline defined as $x = 0$ or $x = 1$? Typically baseline means the absence of treatment, so I assume $x = 0$ represents this.

Second, you say that the baseline is known to be $0$, which I don't understand as you have included $y_0$ in your model. Perhaps you intend to make $\beta_0$ the baseline at the end of the study as opposed to the beginning?

Comment: @MaximilianAigner thank you for the comment. It is a bit different. There is no "absence of treatment", instead baseline is the moment of randomization. And yes, trying to determine $y(t=0)$ if $y_0=0$ is known, is problematic, which is actually exactly the point of my question. As this type of model is common practice in medical statistics and recommended by EMA and FDA, I expect that the interpretation of it should be well documented, but I was not able to find it.